# How can I post two objects simultaneously with axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have a problem like this; I want to post two objects at the same time with axios, but I realized that it is not with the following codes. How do you think I can post two objects at the same time?

```
let companyAry = this.toFormData(this.company[0]);
let productsAry = this.toFormData(this.basket[0]);

axios.post('http://localhost/post', companyAry, productAry)
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.data.message);

});
```

Comment: You can combine company and basket objects to one parent object.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine company and basket objects to one parent object.

```
let params = {
    companyData: companyAry,
    productData: productAry
  }

let res = await axios.post('your url in here', params);
```

Comment: Thank you for help me first. But don't work this code. Because I look console.log return "undefined"

Comment: Lets give it a try by adding decleration for params. I only gave this code block to give you an opinion about issue. Don’t tried it on compiler. Add “var” or “let” before params.

Comment: In which part it didn't work exactly? Can you give detail about error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var output = Object.assign(companyAry, productsAry );
```

Comment: Don't send post "productsAry"  inside datas?